# How to use links in Medium Editor?

Tags: javascript, medium-editor

I've been trying out the excellent [Medium Editor](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor).  The problem that I've been having is that I can't seem to get links to "work".

At the simplest, here's some HTML/JS to use to demonstrate the problem:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/medium-editor/latest/js/medium-editor.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/medium-editor/latest/css/medium-editor.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/medium-editor/latest/css/themes/beagle.min.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class='editable'>
    Hello world.  <a href="http://www.google.com">link</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable');
```

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9s64w9o/) demonstrates the problem (using the code above).

- If you hover on the link, a popup appears.
- If you click the link, nothing happens.
- If you click the popup, a form appears where you can edit the link.

It seems to me that clicking the link should take me wherever the link's `href` is targeting.  The only way to use the link is to right click and either open in a new tab or new window -- which I don't want to ask my users to do.

I feel like I must be missing something simple in the configuration (either the [Anchor Preview Options](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor#anchor-preview-options) or the [Anchor Form Options](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor#anchor-form-options)).  Unfortunately, I'm not seeing it.

<sup>In my actual application, I'm *not* using `jQuery`, but I am using `angularjs`.  If a strictly Medium Editor answer doesn't exist, I can fall back to using basic JS or anything that angularjs provides.</sup>

Comment: Sorry mate. Looks like there's no way to get that link to open when you click it unless you disable the anchor preview. You could open an issue in their repo though.

Comment: In this demo [https://yabwe.github.io/medium-editor/demo.html](https://yabwe.github.io/medium-editor/demo.html) the same thing.

Comment: @Louy -- Yeah, I think that's probably what I'll do -- Though if someone fixes the issue in the next 7 days, I'll happily award the bounty to them ;-)

Comment: @Valijon -- That's a clever idea.  Unfortunately, I'm using the editor for user generated content -- I'd have to somehow parse their content on the fly and bind the click handler to each anchor ... That seems a bit much unless I absolutely _have_ to.

Comment: Add event listener for `a` click manually. (In jQuery it can be done, AngularJS don't know)

Comment: I've created an [issue](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/issues/918) for them.  I guess we'll see what they say.

Comment: If you hold shift or control and click the link it will open (control new tab, shift new window) in firefox. In IE 10, holding control and clicking the popup link will work. In Chrome, neither works

Comment: Interesting -- Though, I don't think that I want to have to explain to my users that they need to use IE or firefox and start control clicking all over the place :-).

Comment: @smcd I tried that and it didn't work. This is the expected behaviour TBH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I really wanted when I asked the question was behavior similar to Google Docs when in "edit" mode ([as described by Nate Mielnik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34550874/748858)).  I opened an [issue on the Medium Editor tracker](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/issues/918) and they decided not to implement it as part of the core medium editor, but they noted that they would be happy to have someone add that functionality as an extension.

So, I decided to implement that functionality as an extension as suggested.  It can be found as part of [MediumTools](https://github.com/PatternAI/MediumTools)<sup>1</sup>.  The project is still in very early stages (e.g. I haven't done anything to make the styling look better, or to use better minifying practices, etc. but we'll happily accept Pull Requests for that).

The guts of the code look like this:

```
var ClassName = {
  INNER: 'medium-editor-toolbar-anchor-preview-inner',
  INNER_CHANGE: 'medium-editor-toolbar-anchor-preview-inner-change',
  INNER_REMOVE: 'medium-editor-toolbar-anchor-preview-inner-remove'
}

var AnchorPreview = MediumEditor.extensions.anchorPreview;
GdocMediumAnchorPreview = MediumEditor.Extension.extend.call(
  AnchorPreview, {

    /** @override */
    getTemplate: function () {
      return '<div class="medium-editor-toolbar-anchor-preview">' +
        '  <a class="' + ClassName.INNER + '"></a>' +
        '  -' +
        '  <a class="' + ClassName.INNER_CHANGE + '">Change</a>' +
        '  |' +
        '  <a class="' + ClassName.INNER_REMOVE + '">Remove</a>' +
        '</div>';
    },

    /** @override */
    createPreview: function () {
      var el = this.document.createElement('div');

      el.id = 'medium-editor-anchor-preview-' + this.getEditorId();
      el.className = 'medium-editor-anchor-preview';
      el.innerHTML = this.getTemplate();

      var targetBlank =
          this.getEditorOption('targetBlank') ||
          this.getEditorOption('gdocAnchorTargetBlank');
      if (targetBlank) {
        el.querySelector('.' + ClassName.INNER).target = '_blank';
      }

      var changeEl = el.querySelector('.' + ClassName.INNER_CHANGE);
      this.on(changeEl, 'click', this.handleClick.bind(this));

      var unlinkEl = el.querySelector('.' + ClassName.INNER_REMOVE);
      this.on(unlinkEl, 'click', this.handleUnlink.bind(this));

      return el;
    },

    /** Unlink the currently active anchor. */
    handleUnlink: function() {
      var activeAnchor = this.activeAnchor;
      if (activeAnchor) {
        this.activeAnchor.outerHTML = this.activeAnchor.innerHTML;
        this.hidePreview();
      }
    }
  });
```

As an explanation, I just use medium's flavor of prototypical inheritance to "subclass" the original/builtin `AnchorPreview` extension.  I override the `getTemplate` method to add the additional links into the markup.  Then I borrowed a lot from the base implementation of `getPreview`, but I bound new actions to each of the links as appropriate.  Finally, I needed to have an action for "unlinking" the link when "Remove" is clicked, so I added a method for that.  The unlink method could probably be done a little better using contenteditable magic (to make sure that it is part of the browser's undo stack), but I didn't spend the time to figure that out (though it would make a good Pull Request for anyone interested :-).

<sup><sup>1</sup>Currently, it's *the* only part, but I hope that'll change at some point. . .</sup>

Answer (score 11):

I've found how to bind event.

Here is full event list https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/blob/master/CUSTOM-EVENTS.md

Try to change your code to

```
var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable')
    .subscribe("editableClick", function(e){if (e.target.href) {window.open(e.target.href)}})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fhr18gm1/

Comment: Nice.  This is probably better than what I was trying to do with angular.

Comment: I would wait for official solution, it's not tested in all browsers/devices/etc...

Comment: @mgilson Thank you. After reading your opened issue in Github, I suppose, they will discuss to implement a feature like in Google Docs for links.

Comment: Yep.  I awarded you the bounty because if I didn't award it, then nobody would benefit and your suggestion in the comments (and subsequent solution posted) have allowed me to create a passable solution while they discuss a more permanent solution.  If they don't create a more permanent solution, I might do it myself by extending their anchor preview plugin as they mention in the docs.  Thanks again for helping me out with this problem!

Answer (score 3):

So medium-editor is built on top of the built-in browser support for `contenteditable` elements.  When you instantiate medium-editor, it will add the `contenteditable=true` attribute to whatever element(s) you provided it.

By default, since the text is now editable (the `contenteditable` attribute makes the browser treat it as WYSIWYG text) the browser no longer supports clicking on the links to navigate.  So, medium-editor is not blocking these link clicks from happening, the browsers do it inherently as part of making the text editable.

medium-editor has built in extensions for interacting with links:

- anchor extension

  - allows for adding/removing links
- anchor-preview extension

  - shows a tooltip when hovering a link
  - when the tooltip is clicked, allows for editing the href of the link via the anchor extension

I think the underlying goal of the editor is the misunderstanding here.  The editor allows for editing text, and in order to add/remove/update links, you need to be able to click into it without automatically navigating away. This is what I think of as 'edit' mode.

However, the html produced as a result of editing is valid html, and if you take that html and put it inside an element that does NOT have the `contenteditable=true` attribute, everything will work as expected.  I think of this as 'publish mode'

I look at editors like word or google docs, and you see a similar kind of behavior where when you edit the document, the links don't just navigate away when you click on them, you have to actually choose to navigate them through a separate action after you click the link.  However, on a 'published' version of the document, clicking the link will actually open a browser window and navigate there.

I think this does make for a good suggestion as an enhancement to the existing anchor-preview extension.  Perhaps the tooltip that appears when hovering a link could have multiple options in it (ie Edit Link | Remove Link | Navigate to URL).

**tldr;**

Links are not navigable on click when 'editing' text in a browser via the built-in WYSIWYG support (`contenteditable`).  When not in 'edit' mode, the links will work as expected.
This could make for a nice enhancement to the medium-editor anchor-preview extension.

Answer (score 0):

Working off some ideas from @Valijon in the comments, I was able to get it to work using the following code:

```
var iElement = angular.element(mediumEditorElement);

iElement.on('click', function(event) {
  if (
      event.target && event.target.tagName == 'A' &&
      event.target.href && !event.defaultPrevented) {
    $window.open(event.target.href, '_blank');
  }
});
```

I think the key is that apparently the editor lets the event propogate to the ancestor elements, so I was able to just listen for the click on the top level editor element.

<sup>Here, `$window` is angular's `$window` service -- If you're not using `angularjs`, `window` would do the trick and I used `angular.element` to ease the event listener registry, but you could do it the old-fashioned way (or using the JS framework of your choice).</sup>

Comment: Well, it'll work, but maybe we can add a simple option. How do your users will edit a link then?

Comment: @j0k -- The link is editable if you hover it and then click in the popup (Basically, it's editable the same way that links are usually editable in the medium editor).  Clicking the link directly takes you to the site.